# Video OverLay on FaceBook & Twitter Profile

Tags: facebook, twitter

How to show video overlay (eg: http://www.ispeakvideo.com/examples.php) on FaceBook & Twitter public profile page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter you can not. Facebook, you may have to make an app.

Comment: Is not possible to stream overlay video from external server?

Comment: It is possible to stream a video overlay from an external server, but it is not possible to embed anything on a twitter profile. There is nowhere to embed the code which would add the video.